# How to show the element from XML (SAXParser) to table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jsp, saxparser

I'm working on a web application that users Spring MVC and Hibernate,

I've field that the type is Clob and the value is XML, 
I was successfully parse that and read/print the element using SAXParser method,

[image: result of SAXParser]

I want to show that element (value) to table in my JSP,

[image]

But I got stuck, I can't even reuse that element at all,

this is my code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/Detail-BPJS-TK.html")
public ModelAndView listDetailBPJSTK(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, Exception{
    if(!((request.getParameter("MESSAGEID")) == null)){
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
        //140721438362
        //DetailBPJS detailbpjs = detailbpjsService.get(MESSAGEID);

        //String tes = detailbpjs.getMESSAGEID();
        //System.out.println(tes);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernatesoaappbpjstk.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        String pay = "PAYMENT";
        String sub = "PROCESSED";

        Query query = session.createQuery("from DetailBPJS where TRANSACTION = :tra and SUBTRANSACTION = :sub and MESSAGEID = :mes");
        query.setParameter("tra", pay);
        query.setParameter("sub", sub);
        query.setParameter("mes", MESSAGEID);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List <DetailBPJS> result = query.list();

        if(result.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Please, check the 'No. Billing' again!!");
            System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
            model.addAttribute("errorMessageBPJSTK", "true");
        }else{
            DetailBPJS data = (DetailBPJS)result.get(0);
            String nom1 = data.getTRANSACTION();
            String nom2 = data.getSUBTRANSACTION();
            String nom3 = data.getUUID();
            Clob nom4 = data.getRAWDATA();

            System.out.println(nom1 + " - " + nom2 + " - " + nom3 + " - " + nom4);
            //140721438362

            //convert clob to java.io.reader
            Reader myclob = nom4.getCharacterStream();
            System.out.println(myclob);

            //create InputSource from Reader
            InputSource myinput = new InputSource(myclob);
            System.out.println(myinput);

            try {

                SAXParserFactory factoryz = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxParser = factoryz.newSAXParser();
                System.out.println(saxParser);

                DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler(){
                    boolean b_num   = false;
                    boolean b_krb   = false;
                    boolean b_reqid = false;
                    boolean b_ch    = false;
                    boolean b_kb    = false;
                    boolean b_tgl   = false;
                    boolean tot     = false;
                    boolean jht     = false;
                    boolean jkk     = false;
                    boolean jkm     = false;

                    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageId")){
                            b_num = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:kodeRefBank")){
                            b_krb = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:reqId")){
                            b_reqid = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:chId")){
                            b_ch = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:kodeBank")){
                            b_kb = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:tglTrx")){
                            b_tgl = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("totalAmount")){
                            tot = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJHT")){
                            jht = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJKK")){
                            jkk = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJKM")){
                            jkm = true;
                        }
                    }

                    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException{
                        if (b_num){
                            System.out.println("(1) Value of Billing Number : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            String tust = new String(ch, start, length);
                            System.out.println(tust);
                            b_num = false;
                        }
                        if (b_krb){
                            System.out.println("(2) Value Of KodeRefBank : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_krb = false;
                        }
                        if (b_reqid){
                            System.out.println("(3) Value Of ReqId : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_reqid = false;
                        }
                        if (b_ch){
                            System.out.println("(4) Value Of ChId : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_ch = false;
                        }
                        if (b_kb){
                            System.out.println("(5) Value Of KodeBank : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_kb = false;
                        }
                        if (b_tgl){
                            System.out.println("(6) Value Of TglTrx : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_tgl = false;
                        }
                        if (tot){
                            System.out.println("(7) Value Of Tot : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            tot = false;
                        }
                        if (jht){
                            System.out.println("(8) Value Of JHT : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jht = false;
                        }
                        if (jkk){
                            System.out.println("(9) Value Of JKK : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jkk = false;
                        }
                        if (jkm){
                            System.out.println("(10) Value Of JKM : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jkm = false;
                        }
                    }
                };
                saxParser.parse(myinput, handler);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            //SAX Parser to parse this xml

        }
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please, check the 'No. Billing' again!!");
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
        model.addAttribute("errorMessageBPJSTK", "true");
    }

    return listDetailBPJS(model);
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Put those values in the model map and show them in your JSP. As simple as that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mushfek0001 how I suppose to do?? the value that I want to put is the result from SAXParser, can I?? because I've tried it an it goes error

Comment: Yes it will give error. Now the actual problem is you are doing so many different types of work in this single handler method. Controllers should be simple. They receive requests, gets data from corresponding services and then sends response. You are doing all those service/DAO layer works here. Scratch out the database and XML parsing to a separate service class. Construct an object to hold your data (e.g. billing number, total amount). You should pass the `MESSAGEID` to your service and it should return you the object. Then put that object in the model map. This should be the way to do it.

Comment: @mushfek0001 yeah I know it, this method exception for my controller.. I've service and DAO layer but not for this method... but can I construct all my data (e.g. billing number etc) without change all my code ~